# iframe video not displaying correctly

Tags: javascript, css, html, angularjs, iframe

I'm trying to embed videos on my website using iframes. The videos display fine in Chrome, but in Firefox and Safari, the videos are enlarged and only a portion of it can be seen. I tried using transformations, but to no avail. I also tried different dimensions, percentages, and auto for the iframe and the div. None of those worked. Thank you for the help in advance.

Links to screenshots:

Firefox: http://puu.sh/cb8Mk/2c7e268cba.png

Chrome: http://puu.sh/cb8OH/7abe55f0e2.png

Safari: http://puu.sh/cb8WJ/22873cdaaa.png

This is what happens when I try to use transformations with Firefox:
http://puu.sh/cbaZa/61e9c241c6.png

I'm using AngularJS. Here is the HTML and CSS.

```
<div id="video-container">
  <iframe id="iframe-video" height="285px" width="510px" ng-src="{{ videoMove }}" frameborder="0" controls></iframe>
</div>
```

```
#video-container {
    float:right;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 60%;
    height: 285px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color: #000000;
}

#iframe-video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: Where are the videos hosted?   Sometimes embedding a video brings in js/css.  Also, try setting the dimension in css OR inline on the iframe itself.  Don't do both, it can confuse a lot of browsers.

Comment: Different Browsers handle `iframe`s differently. I noticed this when I put a PDF into an `iframe` on several Browsers. In some Browsers, the contents will fit, in others you will see just part of a page. It's technologically a different window. Make sure the stuff that goes into your `iframe` is the same exact size as the `iframe`, including padding, margins, and border.

Comment: @jorblume the videos are in a public folder.

Comment: Then I would set the dimensions in the css and forget about the inline styles.

Comment: @jorblume i removed the dimensions in the iframe tag, and set them in the CSS, but that didn't change anything. :/

Comment: remove the float, set the position to relative, and remove the overflow:hidden;  I think the overflow:hidden is allowing the inner container to go outside of the bounds of the box.

Comment: Since when does an `iframe` have `controls`?

Comment: @jorblume that didn't work. it just moved he entire div to the left of the screen. looking at the videos, it seems that Firefox is zooming in for some reason.

Comment: give me a link to the page and I can play around with the css in chrome dev tools

Comment: using iframes sounds like a bad idea

Comment: Some example for adding videos http://webdesignerwall.com/demo/elastic-videos/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try using a `<video>` tag instead of an iframe.

Comment: ng-src doesn't work with the video tag.
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1352